# References for 2d dynamic lighting in iOS environment.

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, 2d, lighting

I'm looking to implement 2d dynamic lighting in my Cocos2d game project similar to the video link below.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mVlYsGOkkyM

I believe that I need to look into OpenGL, but the only references that I can find are for 3d programming. What should I look into in order to manipulate alpha value over a given radius and theta. Thank you.